# Python dot product with large dimension memory problems

Tags: python, pca, dot-product

I have matrix X with dimensions (36000, 3600)
And I`m trying to calculate Sigma=X*X_transpose, as part of implementing PCA algorithm

X is C_CONTIGUOUS

Tried directly and with a loop on the second dimension, both ended with memory problems (my computer is running out of memory, running on 8GB)

What is the best way to achieve that?
Attaching my code

I am new to python (but not to programming), this is the first thing I`m trying to do, so any tips are welcomed!

Thanks a lot

```
class PCAProjector:

def __init__(self, X):
    d, n = X.shape
    self.X = X
    self.Sigma = np.zeros((d,d), dtype='float32', order='C')
    for i in range(n):
        print(i)
        x_i = np.zeros((d,1), dtype='float32', order='C')
        x_i = x_i + X[:,[i]]
        x_i_transpose = np.zeros((1,d), dtype='float32', order='C')
        x_i_transpose = x_i_transpose + np.transpose(x_i)
        i_result = np.dot(x_i, x_i_transpose)
        self.Sigma = self.Sigma + i_result

    self.Sigma = self.Sigma / n
    self.EigenVectorsSorted = EigenVecValculator().calEigenVectors(self.Sigma)

def projectAllSamples(self, numOfDimensions):
    """
    Projects samples to numOfDimensions dimensions

    Projects samples that were passed in Ctor (self.X)
    :param numOfDimensions: number of dimensions to project on
    :return: matrix of (numOfDimensions)X(numOfSamples) that contains the projected samples
    """
    transformationMatrix = self.EigenVectorsSorted[:, 0:numOfDimensions]
    return np.transpose(transformationMatrix)*self.X
```

Comment: "memory problems"?

Comment: Out of memory??

Comment: Yes, by "memory problems" I meant that my computer is running out of memory. I`m running my code on 8GB laptop.